# refinery cms using custome devise views and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, refinerycms

I have used [refinery_cms](http://refinerycms.com/) with my Rails 3.2.8 app. It is configured correctly and it is also working fine. But now I want to implement all my devise views and controllers explicitly as I will be modifying them a bit.

So for that I followed this article

http://sdownie.com/blogs/integrating-refinery-rails-3-2-into-your-existing-rails-app

After doing all the configuration mentioned in the above article, I am getting the following error and I have difficulty tracking the root cause:

This is the error:

```
undefined method `refinery' for #<#<Class:0xcdec518>:0xcdd4fd0>
```

The above error occurs when I am removing the following line from routes.rb:

```
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
```

But if I am keeping the above line and visiting the page `http://localhost:3000/user/sign_up` , I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `user_registration_path' for # <ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0xe189634>
```

Any idea on this will be really helpful

Comment: Please provide the code from the relevant controller. Where do you call the refinery method and what is it supposed to do?

Simply following a tutorial is good for a start. But imho you have to understand what is happening ...

Comment: Hi, Dean did you get any valid answer i'm facing the same problem if you have a right solution please share it with me thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to add some controllers and views in your existing Refinery app , not to integrate refinery into your existing ordinary app . In this case there are a couple of possibilities :

- adding new features to your existing devise controller by writing decorators , according to [the guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/extending-controllers-and-models-with-decorators) (I guess you know Refinery is relying on Devise gem too )
- make all other functionality as mountable engine , explained in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/333-extending-refinery-cms) or any other source , related to engines in Rails 3 .

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys this is a conventional problem solution is so simple follow the steps given below.

```
(1)rake generate devise:views

(2)append "user" before helper urls for example if there is a helper url used in rails   forms

**new_registration_path** then update it as **new_user_registration_path** 

 Similarly whenever you get the same error then go to app/views/devise/ respective     template and check the url used there where error comes and update it as we updated above.
```

Hope this all makes sense.

Thanks.